# You're a pretty good shot

Tags: riddle

> If you get me you're a pretty good shot,
>   But I'm so wanted I have dollars on my head
>   You want to call George, Henry or Isaac?
>   You'll find me in one of my suits, **if you know what I am?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know this:

> The number 4

If you get me you're a pretty good shot,

> A 4 is a good shot in cricket

But I'm so wanted I have dollars on my head

> $ is above the 4 key on a keyboard

You want to call George, Henry or Isaac?

> G, H and I are the letter on the 4 key (?) on a phone

You'll find me in one of my suits, if you know what I am?

> 4 suit of cards with the number 4 in them

Comment: All correct except the first clue, but its another sport

Comment: Now you got them all well done!

Comment: Yeah...I just face-palmed myself for being an Indian and thinking golf over cricket.

Comment: :P you can't get better than cricket!

Answer (score 10):

Answer

> Tailor/Taylor

Reasoning:
If you get me you're a pretty good shot,

> Reference to [Taylor Shotguns](http://www.taylorsfirearms.com)

But I'm so wanted I have dollars on my head

> Reference to the [Zachary Taylor dollar coin](http://catalog.usmint.gov/zachary-taylor-2009-one-dollar-coin-cover-P32.html)

You want to call [George](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Taylor_(delegate)), [Henry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Taylor_(artist)) or [Isaac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Taylor)?

> All famous people named Taylor

You'll find me in one of my suits, if you know what I am?

> A tailor will make you a suit.

Comment: oooh afriad not, nice idea though

Answer (score 2):

Other answers be damned, I like mine!!

> Buck

If you get me you're a pretty good shot,

> Buckshot is can be tough to work with

But I'm so wanted I have dollars on my head

> A buck is slang for a buck

You want to call George, Henry or Isaac?

> George Washington is on the US one dollar note.
>  Sir Henry Parkes was on the Australian one dollar note.
>  Sir Issac Newton was on the British one pound note.

You'll find me in one of my suits, if you know what I am?

> Deer wear deerskin suits, or at least most of the parts of one. They look nice on them, adorable little things! Have you ever seen a deerskin suit on a human? 
> Here's Teddy Roosevelt in one. 
> I guess... the buck DOES stop here. 
> Hahaha I know that's really Truman's quote...[image]